# Print matrix elements in diamond pattern using python

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, data-structures, traversal

I need to traverse and print the matrix elements in a diamond pattern.

```
matrix = [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5], 
          [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10], 
          [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 
          [16, 17, 18, 19, 20], 
          [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]
```

Output:
`[13, 8, 14, 18, 12, 3, 9, 15, 19, 23, 17, 11, 7, 4, 10, 20, 24, 22, 16, 6, 2, 5, 25, 21, 1]`

Comment: Are you familiar with [`for`-loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)? If the matrix is square with odd sidelength `n`, then the centre element (here `13`) has coordinates `(n//2, n//2)`. The element above it (here `8`) has coordinates `(n//2 - 1, n//2)`. And then you move diagonally by adding `1` both vertically and horizontally.

Comment: So you loop over the diamonds, and then inside that loop, for each of the four sides of the diamond, you loop over the elements of the side... etc

Comment: Anyway, this open letter might or might not provide you with some motivation: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Create a program to print in diamond pattern
import math;
matrix = [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5], 
          [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10], 
          [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 
          [16, 17, 18, 19, 20], 
          [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]

def printDiamond(matrix):
    round = 0
    # Start with the row and col in the center of the matrix
    row = math.floor(len(matrix) / 2)
    col = math.floor(len(matrix[0]) /2)
    new_list = []

    # Subtract number of rows as number of rounds
    # Add one col and add one row - repeat until reaching the center row
    # Subtract one col and add one row - repeat until reaching the center column
    # Subtract one col and subtract one row - repeat until reaching the center row
    # Subtract one row and add one col - repeat until reaching the center column
    movements = {'down_right':[1,1],'down_left':[1,-1],'up_left':[-1,-1],'up_right':[-1,1]}
    directions = [movements['down_right'],movements['down_left'],movements['up_left'],movements['up_right']]
    
    for round in range(len(matrix)):
        # Go upwards first
        new_row = row - round
        new_col = col
        try:
            if new_row >= 0:
                # Make sure that the indices are 0 or positive
                #print(matrix[new_row][col])
                new_list.append(matrix[new_row][col])
        except IndexError:
            # By subtracting round from row to make new row
            # Negative indices will exist
            pass
        for direction in directions:
            # Move in the correct direction 
            # And repeat the number of times equal to the current round
            for pos in range(round):
                new_row += direction[0]
                new_col += direction[1]
                try:
                    if (new_row >= 0 and new_col >= 0):
                        if (matrix[new_row][new_col] not in new_list):
                            new_list.append(matrix[new_row][new_col])
                            # print(matrix[new_row][new_col])
                    
                except IndexError:
                    pass
    return new_list

new_list = printDiamond(matrix)
print(new_list)
```

Comment: Doesn't work correctly for a 4x4 matrix, or 2x2 matrix, or 2x4 matrix, ....

Comment: No it won't work for any even matrix. Also, with an even matrix, you would have to decide which position you want the pattern to start since there is no middle element.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply print each row with :

```
for row in matrix :
    print(row)
```

You will have the following output :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
```

Comment: And what about the diamond shape?

Comment: No, I need to iterate through each element like diamond pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You could divide the work into two tasks:

- Create an iterator over the *coordinates* in "diamond order"
- Use that iterator to pick up the values from the matrix

```
def diamond_iter(x, y):
    yield x, y
    for distance in range(1, x + y + 1):
        y -= 1
        for dx, dy in (1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1), (1, -1):
            for _ in range(distance):
                yield x, y
                x += dx
                y += dy
    
def diamond_list(matrix):
    height = len(matrix)
    if not height:
        return []
    width = len(matrix[0])
    return list(matrix[y][x]
                    for x, y in diamond_iter(width // 2, height // 2)
                    if 0 <= x < width and 0 <= y < height)
    
matrix = [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5], 
          [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10], 
          [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 
          [16, 17, 18, 19, 20], 
          [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]

lst = diamond_list(matrix)
print(lst)
```